# How do I enable AES-NI (hardware acceleration) for Node.js crypto on Linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, cryptography, aes, aes-ni

I wrote a basic function to test the speed of the AES-256-CBC mode of the Node.js built-in crypto functions.  These functions use OpenSSL, so they should support AES-NI, but when I correctly enable AES-NI and do a command-line test of OpenSSL the encryption speed is ~350MB/s on OpenSSL and only ~100MB/s on Node.js Crypto.

I used [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/different-performance-of-openssl-speed-on-the-same-hardware-with-aes-256-evp-an) to enable OpenSSL AES-NI in the command line and ran it as follows:

`openssl speed -evp aes-256-cbc`

My question is, how do I make the speed of the Node.js crypto functions for AES match that of OpenSSL run in the command line?  I suspect the reason is failure to use AES-NI

Comment: Did you compile node or using a binary

Comment: Compiled it v 0.10.20

Comment: If you are using the latest openssl, you don't need to do anything. This optimisation is done when compiling openssl with -mtune/-maes flag. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11815/where-can-i-find-information-about-how-to-implement-intel-embedded-aes256-encryp . Right now I don't know if these options are used or not. All I know is that it is compiled with node-gyp for that, see https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/openssl/openssl.gyp.

Comment: 350MB/s is pretty low for AES-NI based AES, I would have expected about twice that number. I wonder if that's caused by CBC encryption being sequential. Do your numbers differ for CBC decryption or CTR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this was not correctly enabled until the latest release v0.12 (that was just released publicly).

Some of the notes are available here
http://strongloop.com/strongblog/performance-node-js-v-0-12-whats-new/

Answer (score 2):

No, you are doing it right. The performance of OpenSSL in Node is a bit disappointing. Most production Node.js deployments terminate SSL connections in something other than Node.js and then forward the unencrypted connections to Node.js.